# response.redirect giving bad request

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have a simple Jquery dialog box, that dialog contains a button which sends the page to the server. After some checking, the server redirects the page to another page.

When I call response.redirect(url+params), it appends the HTML in the URL and displays a bad-request on the browser.

What am I doing wrong here?

I don't have any update panels or non-asp controls on the page.

I am not sure if its important but I am using .Net 1.1

Edit:
Sorry guys, I just found the bug, I was sending the page to the server using ajax call, and the querystring had two "?". Thanks all.

Thanks,
Ali

Comment: What do you mean by "it appends the HTML in the URL"?

Comment: We won't know until some code is posted.

Comment: Show us how you're creating the request, the actual request being created, the actual error being observed, etc.  If I were to guess based on what you've shared so far then I'd focus on the statement "appends the HTML in the URL."  If you're putting unencoded HTML in a request query string then it's entirely likely that either IIS can't interpret the request, the web application can't interpret it, or the default security mechanisms that help protect against things like XSS are rejecting the request.

Comment: http://10.3.62.211/FMH/page_source/%3C!DOCTYPE%20HTML%20PUBLIC%20%22%//W3C//DTD%20HTML%204.01%20Transitional//EN%223E%3Chtml%3E%20%20%3Chead%3E%3Ctitle%3E%3C/title%3E%20%20%3C/head%3

Comment: The target page does not have doctype would that be a problem?

Comment: `response.redirect(url+params)` does not give enough information to understand what's happening? How does the button send the page to the server? You're going to need to post some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're sending this data to the Server through an Ajax call, .NEt will  not be able to redirect it.

You will need to either do a JavaScript redirect (http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/javascriptredirect.php), or do a full server round trip.

A SO question on this: [Cannot do response.redirect from page with Ajax controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1215177/cannot-do-response-redirect-from-page-with-ajax-controls)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure in the Browser address bar that the page is redirecting to a page that **exists**